# angular type=[number] directive to block paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am looking for a way to block paste into numeric directive.
I though about blocking all the paste events, I had done it before in jQuery, but I failed to do the same with angular.
This is the jQuery code, I understand that I need to extent the [input[number]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) directive, but I can't find any example of extending this directive.

```
$("input[type='number']").on('paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = prompt('set content here');
    this.value = (value)?value.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''):0;
})
```

I would appreciate a code skeleton or demo of extending the input[number] directive so I can change for this porpuse.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of extending the directive, I just created another one on top of it...
Hopes it will help anyone who need this solution

```
myApp.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            if ($attrs.type == 'number') {
                $element.on('paste', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var value = prompt('paste content here');
                    this.value = (value)?value.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''):0;
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```